# problemas importando un fichero a otro en python

Tags: python, importación

realmente eso fue todo, estoy intentando hacer una IA para un 3 en raya que programe en un fichero aparte, en la misma carpeta y me esta lanzando el error `Import "main" could not be resolved pylance(reportMissingImports) [20, 6]`

probe a importarlo de estas dos formas:

`import main` y `from main import *`

Ambos ficheros estan dentro de una carpeta que esta dentro de otra junto otras dos, dicha carpeta la tengo en el escritorio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esa es la carpeta, queremos importar "main" a "pruebas_IA"

alguna idea de mi error?

Comment: me podrias explicar a que te refiers con estructura de mis directorios? soy un poco nuevo en todo esto jaja

Comment: ahhh, tengo una carpeta en el escritorio que tiene 3 carpetas dentro, la primera de ella tiene 3 ficheros .py, el primero lo quiero importar al segundo

Comment: claro, una captura de la direccion o de la carpeta?

Comment: probá cambiando el nombre del archivo main a principal por ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta fue la solución encontrada al final, hice caso al ultimo comentario y traduje el nombre al castellano y evite usar caracteres que no fuesen letras, también quite la carpeta de trabajo de la otra carpeta y la deje en el escritorio directamente.

gracias a quienes se preocuparon por ayudar, espero que esto sirva si se repite el error con alguien.